# Updating a SQLite entry row

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am looking to update a row in SQLite data base. what I am wondering is can I update a row without having the user enter in the rowId? My code at the moment requires the rowId to be passed into the DBAdapter but i would like to eliminate this and just update the row using the other two variables(item and litres). Is this even possible?

This is my update function in my DBAdapter class

```
//---updates a record---
public boolean updateRecord(long rowId, String item, String litres)
{
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_ITEM, item);
    args.put(KEY_LITRES, litres);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

this is my update class,

```
package com.example.rory.dbtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.pinchtapzoom.R;


public class Update extends Activity {

public EditText updateItem;
public EditText updateLitres;
Button updateBtn;

DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);

    updateBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.updateBtn);
    updateItem = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.updateItem);
    updateLitres = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.updateLitres);
}


public void onClick(View v)
{
   String item = updateItem.getText().toString();
   String litres = updateLitres.getText().toString();
   db.updateRecord(rowId, String item, String litres);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.update, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

//returning to the first activity, when here this calls the running functions ie. printing records
public void viewAssignments(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

Comment: Then what is the unique Constraint in where clause?

Comment: Could I change the constraint to return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ITEM + "=" + item, null) > 0;

Comment: this is what i have changed the update function to in my DBAdapter and now i am only passing in the two values but i am getting an error for this'    public boolean updateRecord(String item, String litres)
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_ITEM, item);
        args.put(KEY_LITRES, litres);
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ITEM + "=" + item, null) > 0;
    }'

Answer (score 0):

I am using this section of code in my project.

```
@Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs) {
            String sql = "UPDATE table_name SET product_qty = \'"+values.getAsString("product_qty")+"\' Where row_id = \'"+selectionArgs[0]+"\'"+" ; ";

            Log.e("sql", sql) ;

            db_cc.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(sql);

            return 0;
    }
```

Where i am passing my row_id in [0]th position of selectionArgs array, and in my case i want to update product_qty so i have passed that value by using ContentValues .

Comment: so are you using this code to update using the product_qty and not the row_id?

Comment: no, i am using condition Where row_id = \'"+selectionArgs[0], then setting product_qty = \'"+values.getAsString("product_qty")

Answer (score 0):

You can make RAW Updates as easy as this:

```
public boolean updateRecord(String item, String litres)
{
    return db.execSQL("UPDATE "+DATABASE_TABLE+" SET "+KEY_LITRES+"='"+litres+"' WHERE "+KEY_ITEM+"='"+item+"'")
}
```

But **this will update all rows with KEY_ITEM=item** condition OR...
You can add another parameter, like this:

```
public boolean updateRecord(String item, String litres, String newLitres)
{
    return db.execSQL("UPDATE "+DATABASE_TABLE+" SET "+KEY_LITRES+"='"+newLitres+"' WHERE "+KEY_ITEM+"='"+item+"' AND "+KEY_LITRES+"='"+litres+"'")
}
```

and this will update only the row with the given parameters of item AND liter
BUT if you have 2 or more rows with same item and liters, then there will be a problem.

I still recommend to use unique keys or primary keys instead.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am a little unsure about this, can you tell me if i am right in saying that, by replacing my update function with this code in my DBAdapter class then calling this function in my update class and send the correct variables in it will update the entry?

Comment: thats right Hayes121, you're originally sendind 3 parameters to your updateRecord() function, so i think that if you want not to include the rowId, but the other two parameters, then this is your answer, but to be more specific, you may want to include the third (newLitres) in case you want to change that value.

Comment: cool thank you, one last thing, when i entered in the code you gave above it is giving me a red error line under all the text it says that it requires a boolean and is getting a void, to fix this I thought I wouldl just put the dbexecSQL into a boolean value but that didnt work, any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: actually you're right, the method execSQL return nothing (void), you have three choices, 1.- turn your function from boolean to void or 2.- use a  try/catch that returns TRUE on success or 3.- always return true